# .NET Core 3.0 GA side-by-side with .NET Core 3.0 Preview 8

Tags: iis, .net-core

Is there a way to have .NET Core 3.0 GA and .NET Core Preview 8 run side-by-side on on the same IIS machine?

I have a set of QA and Production IIS machines which originally had .NET Core 3.0 Preview 8 Hosting Bundle. Some teams opted to go to Production with Preview 8 with their IIS hosted web applications because MS said that it was supported for production. Now that .NET Core 3.0 General Availability has been released, I installed this into the QA machine expecting Preview 8 to be left alone. As the installation ran, I saw the words "Previous installation" flash by on the progress bar and it made my stomach drop. When the installation finished, I found that Preview 8 had been uninstalled, and only the GA was left installed on the machine.

If I can't have the two versions running side-by-side, that will mean that my original plan to let teams transition from Preview 8 to GA as their sprint schedules allows them to do so. Now the various teams will be force to drop everything, do testing against GA, as well as synchronize their Production deployments with the installation of GA into Production.

Or is this a non-issue because Preview 8 and GA sufficiently close to each other, than the teams really need to be doing something esoteric to hit upon any of the bugs and breaking changes between the two builds? e.g. It won't matter if they test against GA in the QA environment, and then go into Production which is running Preview 8. (I will admit that I've not yet dug through the list of bug fixes and breaking changes because originally I thought I'd have time to do this later while the two builds ran side-by-side.)

Or is this a non-issue because each web application has been built with all the binaries it needs, and the only thing that my IIS machines are providing to these teams is just the AspNetCoreModuleV2 ISAPI handler?

Comment: Can you file an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/core? I don't think this pre-production upgrade scenario was a planned feature but should be considered.

Comment: Does installing the preview 8 afterwards again fix the issue? the installer should only uninstall lower versions, but not higher ones.

Comment: Running the Preview 8 installer executable just brings up options to Repair or Uninstall.

Comment: I've opened issue #3441.

Comment: You can only install a single version of .NET Core 3.0 SDK, or server hosting bundle, while you can install multiple versions of the runtime. So only the runtime is capable of side by side. It would be rather difficult to comment whether the GA server hosting bundle can work flawlessly with preview 8 runtime, so you did the right thing to ask Microsoft directly.